# Handle 'ssh2_auth_password()' error upon wrong credentials

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssh, exception, basic-authentication

I'm kind of struggling to when it comes to handle error on `ssh2_auth_password()` function (and `ssh2_connect()` as well). I manage successfully on connecting and login to my remote server, however, when it comes to supply wrong credentials, I would like to be able to handle those cases. I'm using ZF 1.12 and I've created a little controller plugin as so:

```
<?php
class My_Controller_Plugin_Scp extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    private $host;
    private $login;
    private $password;
    private $destDir = '.';
    private $connexion;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $co = ssh2_connect($this->getHost(), 22);
        if(false === $co)
            throw new Exception('Can\'t connect to remote server');

        $this->setConnexion($co);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function auth()
    {
        $auth = ssh2_auth_password($this->getConnexion(), $this->getLogin(), $this->getPassword());

        if($auth === false)
            throw new Exception('Authentication failed!');

        return $auth;
    }
```

And I'm using this plugin in my controller like this:

```
    try {
        // Préparation à la copie en SSH du fichier template
        $scp = new My_Controller_Plugin_Scp();
        $scp->auth(); // Authentification
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $this->getHelper('Redirector')->setGotoRoute(array(), 'ficheVoir');
        exit();
    }
```

The actual output is, when I mess up the credentials, a PHP warning is thrown whereas I would like to be able to display a custom error message.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with `Exception` and stuff?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: It says `Warning: ssh2_auth_password(): Authentication failed for login using password` as expected because I supplied wrong credentials.

Comment: This might be stupid but try not to assign the returning value to `$auth` variable and call the function from `if`. Also, try to suppress the errors with @.

Comment: I have already tried not to assign `$auth` to `return` and suppress error with `@` but I'm left with a blank page instead of going to the `catch()` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to test your code because a lot of things were missing.
I wrote a simple connect function based on your code:

```
<?php

function connect() {
    $host = '';
    $login = '';
    $password = '';
    $co = ssh2_connect($host, 22);
    if (false === $co)
        throw new Exception('Can\'t connect to remote server');
    $result = @ssh2_auth_password($co, $login, $password);
    var_dump($result);
    if ($result === false) {
        throw new Exception('Authentication failed!');
    }
    echo 'Connection estabilished';
}

try {
    connect();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

I am suppressing PHP warnings using `@` not to throw ugly PHP error messages. If `$result` is `false` an `Exception` is thrown and is being handled properly. Basically, the solution is just to add `@` before `ssh2_auth_password()` function.

Comment: Thanks to your `echo $e->getMessage()`, I'm able to see it goes indeed into the `catch()` expression but somehow, it doesn't want to execute Zend Redirector Helper. I'm investigating on that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I've managed to modify Zend Redirector Helper in order to work in catch{} expression. Here is how I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887138/cannot-redirect-in-try-catch-with-zf1-12-redirector-helper