# Cannot redirect in try/catch with ZF1.12 Redirector helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, helper

I'm facing a weird problem. It appears I cannot use ZF1.12 `Redirector` Helper in the `catch() {}` expression. Here is my code:

```
    try {
        $scp = new My_Controller_Plugin_Scp();
        $scp->auth();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     // $this->getHelper('Redirector')->setGotoRoute(array(), 'routeName');
        $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl('/url/');
        exit();
    }
```

It appears that using route names in the helper (commented out line) doesn't work in the `catch() {}` expression.  Code is interpreted as the flash message appears when I go manually to another page (and the `echo $e->getMessage()` is displayed on the error page) but it simply doesn't redirect where it should as I'm left with a blank page. The next line after the commented one is, of course, working.

I want to use route names as I may change URL afterwards.

Many thanks.

Comment: Apparently, I needed to use `gotoRoute()` method instead of `setGotoRoute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed `gotoRoute` is something you are looking for:

```
try {

    throw new Exception('test');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    //displaying message before redirect is not a good idea.
    //Use flash messages
    echo $e->getMessage();

    $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRouteAndExit(array(), 'home');
}
```